# ArangoDb Transactions in typescript with webpack bundler

Tags: typescript, webpack, transactions, arangodb

I was trying to perform transactional operation using arangojs library. Action function looks basically like this:

```
String(function (params) {
    var db = require('@arangodb').db;
    var offer = db.offer.insert(params.offer, {waitForSync: true, returnNew: true});

    params.offerItems.forEach(oi => {
        oi.offer_key = offer._key;
    });

    db.offeritem.insert(params.offerItems, {waitForSync: true});

    return offer;
});
```

This function is stringified and sent to the arangodb server where it is parsed back to the js funcion and executed.

The problem is that **webpack** is trying to find `@arangodb` module, which isn't icluded in `node_modules` so he throws an exception.

I've managed to resolve the problem by replacing `var db = require('@arangodb').db;` with `var db = global['require']('@arangodb').db;` which webpack leaves intact, but i'm looking for better solution (If there is some).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a JavaScript developer on the ArangoDB team.

You probably don't want Webpack to touch code you intend to run in ArangoDB. The `String(function() {...})` syntax is something we use in documentation and examples to make the code easier to read. It converts the function to a string so you can send it across the wire but allows you to use syntax highlighting while writing the function.

I would suggest using a template string instead:

```
`function (params) {
    var db = require('@arangodb').db;
    var offer = db.offer.insert(params.offer, {waitForSync: true, returnNew: true});

    params.offerItems.forEach(oi => {
        oi.offer_key = offer._key;
    });

    db.offeritem.insert(params.offerItems, {waitForSync: true});

    return offer;
}`;
```

This allows you to keep the code as multiple lines but Webpack will just see it as a string and not try to do anything with it. Keep in mind this also means the code won't be minified.

Note that we do not recommend accessing ArangoDB from the browser in production. Instead of exposing the entire database (and anything the user account has access to), it's probably a better idea to create a more limited API your frontend can access, e.g. using [Foxx](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Foxx/) or Node.js.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I'm accessing ArangoDB from node, so it's safe.

Comment: @Yess just in case you haven't yet, remember to give arangojs 6 a try. We rewrote the entire driver in TypeScript so the type declarations are far more accurate now: https://www.arangodb.com/2018/01/arangojs-6-0-0-released-load-balancing-automated-failover-completely-written-typescript/

Comment: @AlanPlum Thanks, I had the same issue and your answer nearly got me out of the jam. However, inside the function that I now have as a string literal, I'm also writing a query using the `aql` function, which as you know requires more backticks. I tried simply escaping them with a backslash, but I get a runtime error on my first `${params._key}` that params is not defined. Seems like it's still trying to sub in the string literal variables instead of wrapping them into the literal itself. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. After first escaping the inner set of backticks with a backslash, I had to also place a backslash *between* the `$` and `{` for any expression interpolations that I did not want to be part of the parent-most string literal. That got me to where the full string had the properly formatted embedded string literal, complete with backticks and `${}` syntax.